# How much an account creation does cost in USD?

Tags: transactions, accounts

I would like to get an idea of how much does it cost create an account in stellar because I'm planning to create accounts programmatically and I'd like to estimate prices.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fees are extremely low in Stellar. You can find more information at https://developers.stellar.org/docs/glossary/fees/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).